# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception(Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, compiler-errors

I have this error :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**What went wrong:**

**Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalFreeRelease'.**

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
> Could not download lint-kotlin.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.2.1): No cached version available for offline mode
> Could not download intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.2.1): No cached version available for offline mode
> Could not download uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.2.1): No cached version available for offline mode
> Could not download groovy-all.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12): No cached version available for offline mode
> Could not download kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.2.1): No cached version available for offline mode
> Could not download error_prone_annotations.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18): No cached version available for offline mode

* Try:

>Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have enabled offline mode:

[image]

Please try to uncheck Offline work under Settings, sync gradle and try again.